# Preprocessing audio in android Speech Input recognizer

Tags: android, speech-recognition, audio-processing

I'm doing some basic command recognition and using Google Search Input API for that. However I want to capture audio myself, preprocess the audio (denoise, boost amplitude, etc), send those modified audio to the recognizer and obtaining results. Is it possible?

I know you can use `SpeechRecognizer` along with `RecognitionListener` to obtain audio using `onBufferReceived` method. However I want to do preprocessing instead of postprocessing. Is there any workaround/hack to feed google recognizer with processed data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> preprocess the audio (denoise, boost amplitude, etc), send those modified audio to the recognizer and obtaining results

Usually speech recognition systems suffer from this. Incorrectly implemented denoising can lower speech recognitoin accuracy because it corrupts spectrum in unpredictable way. Amplitude boosting doesn't help because amplitude is normalized on the very beginning of speech recognition. Your preprocessing can only hurt.

If you still want to try it, try pocketsphinx

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

Comment: Thx for the tip regarding pitfalls with denoising. I already tested sphinx but it somehow worked really poor with provided apps that's why I wanted to use google recognizer. Is reverse engineering android recognizer activity the only way the do preprocessing then?